# format statement in a string resource file

Tags: android, android-resources

I have strings defined in the usual strings.xml Resource file like this:

```
<string name="hello_world"> HELLO</string>
```

Is it possible to define format strings such as the one below

```
 result_str = String.format("Amount: %.2f  for %d days ",  var1, var2);
```

in the strings.xml resource file?

I tried escaping the special characters but its not working.

Comment: You can try in below way: mTextView.setText(String.format("Score: "+"%1$s", runs)); where int runs = 100;

Answer (score 321, accepted):

You do not need to use `formatted="false"` in your XML.  You just need to use fully qualified string format markers - `%[POSITION]$[TYPE]` (where `[POSITION]` is the attribute position and `[TYPE]` is the variable type), rather than the short versions, for example `%s` or `%d`.

Quote from [Android Docs: String Formatting and Styling](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling):

> ```
> <string name="welcome_messages">Hello, %1$s! You have %2$d new messages.</string>
> ```
>
> In this example, the format string has two arguments: `%1$s` is a
>   string and `%2$d` is a decimal integer. You can format the string with
>   arguments from your application like this:
>
> ```
> Resources res = getResources();
> String text = res.getString(R.string.welcome_messages, username, mailCount);
> ```

Comment: I get  java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: %d can't format java.lang.Double arguments when I use $d think $d is an integer

Comment: Here is a list of all of the different convertors, you'll have to choose the appropriate one for the number type, you may need %f (for floating point): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

Comment: res.getString(R.string.welcome_messages, username, mailCount) will do the job. The getString method of resource/context includes the formatting functionality.

Comment: Best and straightforward solution.

Answer (score 110):

You should add `formatted="false"` to your string resource

---

Here is an example

In your `strings.xml` :

```
<string name="all" formatted="false">Amount: %.2f%n  for %d days</string>
```

In your code:

```
yourTextView.setText(String.format(getString(R.string.all), 3.12, 2));
```

Comment: Not necessary according to the docs for Formatting strings. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling

Comment: That is one way to fix, but might be confusing to some because `formatted="false"` could imply the string does not get formatted.  Posted another solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/20887690/228429

Comment: Note that you can simplify `String.format(getString(R.string.all), 3.12, 2)` this way: `getString(R.string.all, 3.12, 2)`.

Comment: There is a major problem with all the answers in this page: If you need to add a percent sign right next to a param, say `25%`, Android will crash.

Comment: You can escape the percent sign by including two %%.  This following standard formatting syntax.  Example:   String.format("Percent %d%% or as float %.2f%%",  12, 12.34f);   Will generate a string "Percent 12% or as float 12.34%"

Comment: How to fix this problem if string.xml is in library and i can not recompile it ?

Comment: @VytautasBerankis If you redefine the string in your project, it should be overridden

Comment: I will try but there are over 300 strings :/

Answer (score 16):

Inside file `strings.xml` define a String resource like this:

```
<string name="string_to_format">Amount: %1$f  for %2$d days%3$s</string>
```

Inside your code (assume it inherits from Context) simply do the following:

```
 String formattedString = getString(R.string.string_to_format, floatVar, decimalVar, stringVar);
```

(In comparison to the answer from [LocalPCGuy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20887690/5389530) or [Giovanny Farto M.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627457/format-statement-in-a-string-resource-file/24098427#24098427) the String.format method is not needed.)

Answer (score 9):

Quote from [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html):

> If you need to format your strings using `String.format(String,
>   Object...)`, then you can do so by putting your format arguments in the
>   string resource. For example, with the following resource:
>
> ```
> <string name="welcome_messages">Hello, %1$s! You have %2$d new messages.</string>
> ```
>
> In this example, the format string has two arguments: `%1$s` is a string
>   and `%2$d` is a decimal number. You can format the string with arguments
>   from your application like this:
>
> ```
> Resources res = getResources();
> String text = String.format(res.getString(R.string.welcome_messages), username, mailCount);
> ```

Answer (score 4):

For me it worked like that in Kotlin:

my string.xml

```
 <string name="price" formatted="false">Price:U$ %.2f%n</string>
```

my class.kt

```
 var formatPrice: CharSequence? = null
 var unitPrice = 9990
 formatPrice = String.format(context.getString(R.string.price), unitPrice/100.0)
 Log.d("Double_CharSequence", "$formatPrice")
```

D/Double_CharSequence: Price :U$ 99,90

For an even better result, we can do so

```
 <string name="price_to_string">Price:U$ %1$s</string>

 var formatPrice: CharSequence? = null
 var unitPrice = 199990
 val numberFormat = (unitPrice/100.0).toString()
 formatPrice = String.format(context.getString(R.string.price_to_string), formatValue(numberFormat))

  fun formatValue(value: String) :String{
    val mDecimalFormat = DecimalFormat("###,###,##0.00")
    val s1 = value.toDouble()
    return mDecimalFormat.format(s1)
 }

 Log.d("Double_CharSequence", "$formatPrice")
```

D/Double_CharSequence: Price :U$ 1.999,90

Answer (score 1):

**Feb 2024**
Simpley define placeholders in the resource file:
**1.** Use fully qualified placeholders of the form `%[POSITION]$[TYPE]` within your string resource.

- `POSITION` indicates the argument's position (e.g., 1 for the first argument).
- `TYPE` specifies the expected argument type (e.g., s for string, d for decimal).

  Here is a list of the type specifiers and their meanings.[[full list]](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#summary)

| Conversion | Description |
| --- | --- |
| b | Boolean |
| c | Character |
| s | String |
| d | Signed Integer |
| e | Float in Scientific Notation |
| f | Float in Decimal Format |
| g | Float in Decimal or Scientific Notation, depending on value |
| h | Hashcode of the supplied argument |
| o | Octal Integer |
| x | Hexadecimal Integer |
| t | Date or Time |

example :

```
<string name="welcome_message">Hello, %1$s! You have %2$d new messages.</string>
```

**2.** Use methods like `getString()` to retrieve the string resource, providing the necessary arguments for formatting.

**Java :**

```
String username = "Alice";
int messageCount = 5;
String formattedMessage = getString(R.string.welcome_message, username, messageCount);
```

**Kotlin :**

```
val username = "Alice"
val messageCount = 5
val formattedMessage = getString(R.string.welcome_message, username, messageCount)
```

**Jetpack Compose :**

```
val username = "Alice"
val messageCount = 5
Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.welcome_message, username,messageCount))
```