# Android Studio won't run app, 93 errors

Tags: android-studio

So until 30 minutes ago I was able to launch my almost done app. And now when I try to launch it, it fails with 93 ERRORS!

Here's log

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Multiple substitutions specified in non-positional format; did you mean to add the formatted\u003d\"false\" attribute?","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml","position":{"startLine":1725,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":84836,"endLine":1731,"endColumn":19,"endOffset":85341}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Found tag \u003c/item\u003e where \u003c/string-array\u003e is expected","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml","position":{"startLine":1725,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":84836,"endLine":1731,"endColumn":19,"endOffset":85341}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027Base.Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle.Common\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-hdpi-v4/values-hdpi-v4.xml","position":{"startLine":2}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027barLength\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/res/values-hdpi/values-hdpi.xml","position":{"startLine":4,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":235,"endLine":8,"endColumn":13,"endOffset":507}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027drawableSize\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/res/values-hdpi/values-hdpi.xml","position":{"startLine":4,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":235,"endLine":8,"endColumn":13,"endOffset":507}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027gapBetweenBars\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/res/values-hdpi/values-hdpi.xml","position":{"startLine":4,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":235,"endLine":8,"endColumn":13,"endOffset":507}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-sw600dp-v13/values-sw600dp-v13.xml","position":{"startLine":18}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027tabGravity\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/design/23.1.1/res/values-sw600dp/values-sw600dp.xml","position":{"startLine":16,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":1133,"endLine":19,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":1310}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027tabMode\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/design/23.1.1/res/values-sw600dp/values-sw600dp.xml","position":{"startLine":16,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":1133,"endLine":19,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":1310}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-land/values-land.xml","position":{"startLine":8}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027tabGravity\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/design/23.1.1/res/values-land/values-land.xml","position":{"startLine":4,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":224,"endLine":7,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":401}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027tabMode\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/design/23.1.1/res/values-land/values-land.xml","position":{"startLine":4,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":224,"endLine":7,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":401}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027Base.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.FixedSize\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-large-v4/values-large-v4.xml","position":{"startLine":13}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.FixedSize\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-large-v4/values-large-v4.xml","position":{"startLine":14}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v11/values-v11.xml","position":{"startLine":40}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v11/values-v11.xml","position":{"startLine":45}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027selectableItemBackground\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/res/values-v11/values-v11.xml","position":{"startLine":64,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":4734,"endLine":114,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":8437}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027selectableItemBackground\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/res/values-v11/values-v11.xml","position":{"startLine":115,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":8442,"endLine":166,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":12285}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027Base.V7.Widget.AppCompat.AutoCompleteTextView\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v12/values-v12.xml","position":{"startLine":2}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027Base.V7.Widget.AppCompat.EditText\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v12/values-v12.xml","position":{"startLine":5}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027Base.DialogWindowTitle.AppCompat\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v17/values-v17.xml","position":{"startLine":2}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v21/values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":3}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027colorAccent\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/src/main/res/values-v21/styles.xml","position":{"startLine":10,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":370,"endLine":21,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":815}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027colorPrimary\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/src/main/res/values-v21/styles.xml","position":{"startLine":10,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":370,"endLine":21,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":815}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027colorPrimaryDark\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/src/main/res/values-v21/styles.xml","position":{"startLine":10,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":370,"endLine":21,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":815}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027elevation\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/src/main/res/values-v21/styles.xml","position":{"startLine":10,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":370,"endLine":21,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":815}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027windowActionBar\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/src/main/res/values-v21/styles.xml","position":{"startLine":2,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":18,"endLine":8,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":364}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027windowNoTitle\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/src/main/res/values-v21/styles.xml","position":{"startLine":2,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":18,"endLine":8,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":364}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v21/values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":79}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027actionBarDivider\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/res/values-v21/values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":81,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":7212,"endLine":124,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":10275}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027actionBarItemBackground\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/res/values-v21/values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":81,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":7212,"endLine":124,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":10275}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027actionBarSize\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/res/values-v21/values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":81,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":7212,"endLine":124,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":10275}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027actionButtonStyle\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/res/values-v21/values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":81,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":7212,"endLine":124,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":10275}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027actionModeBackground\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/res/values-v21/values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":81,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":7212,"endLine":124,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":10275}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027actionModeCloseDrawable\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/res/values-v21/values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":81,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":7212,"endLine":124,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":10275}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027actionOverflowButtonStyle\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/res/values-v21/values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":81,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":7212,"endLine":124,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":10275}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027borderlessButtonStyle\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/res/values-v21/values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":81,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":7212,"endLine":124,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":10275}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027buttonStyle\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/res/values-v21/values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":81,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":7212,"endLine":124,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":10275}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027buttonStyleSmall\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/res/values-v21/values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":81,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":7212,"endLine":124,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":10275}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027checkboxStyle\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/res/values-v21/values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":81,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":7212,"endLine":124,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":10275}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027checkedTextViewStyle\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/res/values-v21/values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":81,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":7212,"endLine":124,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":10275}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027dividerHorizontal\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/res/values-v21/values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":81,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":7212,"endLine":124,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":10275}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027dividerVertical\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/res/values-v21/values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":81,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":7212,"endLine":124,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":10275}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027editTextBackground\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/res/values-v21/values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":81,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":7212,"endLine":124,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":10275}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027editTextColor\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/res/values-v21/values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":81,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":7212,"endLine":124,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":10275}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027homeAsUpIndicator\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/res/values-v21/values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":81,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":7212,"endLine":124,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":10275}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027listChoiceBackgroundIndicator\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/res/values-v21/values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":81,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":7212,"endLine":124,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":10275}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027listPreferredItemHeightSmall\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/res/values-v21/values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":81,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":7212,"endLine":124,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":10275}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027radioButtonStyle\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/res/values-v21/values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":81,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":7212,"endLine":124,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":10275}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027ratingBarStyle\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/res/values-v21/values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":81,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":7212,"endLine":124,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":10275}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027selectableItemBackground\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/res/values-v21/values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":81,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":7212,"endLine":124,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":10275}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027selectableItemBackgroundBorderless\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/res/values-v21/values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":81,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":7212,"endLine":124,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":10275}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027spinnerStyle\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/res/values-v21/values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":81,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":7212,"endLine":124,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":10275}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027textAppearanceLargePopupMenu\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/res/values-v21/values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":81,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":7212,"endLine":124,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":10275}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/res/values-v21/values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":81,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":7212,"endLine":124,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":10275}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat.Light\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v21/values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":126}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027actionBarDivider\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/res/values-v21/values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":128,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":10466,"endLine":171,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":13541}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027actionBarItemBackground\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/res/values-v21/values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":128,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":10466,"endLine":171,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":13541}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027actionBarSize\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/res/values-v21/values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":128,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":10466,"endLine":171,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":13541}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027actionButtonStyle\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/res/values-v21/values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":128,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":10466,"endLine":171,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":13541}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027actionModeBackground\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/res/values-v21/values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":128,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":10466,"endLine":171,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":13541}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027actionModeCloseDrawable\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/res/values-v21/values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":128,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":10466,"endLine":171,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":13541}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027actionOverflowButtonStyle\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/res/values-v21/values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":128,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":10466,"endLine":171,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":13541}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027borderlessButtonStyle\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/res/values-v21/values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":128,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":10466,"endLine":171,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":13541}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027buttonStyle\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/res/values-v21/values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":128,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":10466,"endLine":171,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":13541}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027buttonStyleSmall\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/res/values-v21/values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":128,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":10466,"endLine":171,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":13541}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027checkboxStyle\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/res/values-v21/values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":128,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":10466,"endLine":171,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":13541}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}



AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027controlBackground\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/home/dario/Dokumenti/LiftMeHR/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/res/values-v23/values-v23.xml","position":{"startLine":18,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":1273,"endLine":26,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":1838}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}


 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/home/dario/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 18.346 secs
```

As you can see it is pretty long. Don't know what to do, every file I open turns red, it can't resolve half of the simbols..

Had to delete some text in the log, it was more then 30000 characters

Anyone has the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be caused by a malformed `strings.xml`. I encountered an almost identical sequence of errors after adding a bad string definition that contained multiple arguments.

I have several definitions that look like `<string name="myString">prefix: %s</string>` which seems to work just fine. Then I tried adding a definition that looks like `<string name="myString">%s, %s</string>`, which resulted in a slew of apparently unrelated `AGPBI:` errors (as seen in the question).

This is the wrong way to declare a string with multiple arguments (the answer to [format statement in a string resource file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627457/format-statement-in-a-string-resource-file) describes the right way). I changed my string definition to `<string name="myString">%1$s, %2$s</string>` and the errors went away.