# String.format or getString

Tags: android, android-resources

In order to format a string, I always use `String.format(getString(R.string.something),arg1)`

However I saw on the documentation `getString(string, args)` could do the same.

Therefore, I wonder why everyone use String.format if getString can do the same

Thank you

Comment: The answer is Yes. See the most upvoted ansewr here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627457/format-statement-in-a-string-resource-file

Comment: @Doomsknight, the question is `Why?`. The answer can't be `Yes`

Comment: @VladMatvienko Wrong wording sorry. By that i mean they are the same, except one is more direct. Not everyone knows of better ways, and as per the linked answer, you can see that the accepted answer denotes one method, and the most upvoted answer, denotes the second. So it is more of what people come across to what is used. I don't always program optimally either. Some APIs are also introduced at a later date, after certain ways of coding are already documented.

Comment: Also noting from the documentation, it shows example usage of the first method, not the second. So people using it as reference follow the first usage. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling

Answer (score 2):

You are mistaken, there is no method `Resources.getString(string, args...)` or `Context.getString(string, args...)`. There is `Resources.getString(int, args...)` that takes an int and objects.

When formatting a string you would use `String.format(string, args...)`. But in Android your string resources are probably in the res folder so you have a convinience method for getting the string from the resources and formatting it with `String.format`. It does the same thing as you did ([taken from Android source](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/4b1a8f46d6ec55796bf77fd8921a5a242a219278/core/java/android/content/res/Resources.java)):

```
@NonNull
public String getString(@StringRes int id, Object... formatArgs) throws NotFoundException {
    final String raw = getString(id);
    return String.format(mResourcesImpl.getConfiguration().getLocales().get(0), raw,
            formatArgs);
}
```

You would use it like:

```
getString(R.string.something, arg1)
```

and save yourself some typing.

Comment: Sorry, yes, you are right. I misunderstood your answer first time because it is written in a quite complicated language.

Comment: I assume his question actually meant `Resources.getString(int, args...)` And that its more aimed at why they use one method over the other