# Invalid format String containing %

Tags: java, android, string, string-formatting, getstring

I've read others posts about this link warning but they didn't solve my problem and I still don't get what I've doing wrong.

In default file strings.xml, I have:

```
 <string name="rating_dialog">You\'re about to rate this app with %s stars.</string>
```

Later, I call it inside an override onClick method:

```
 v.getContext().getString(R.string.rating_dialog, String.valueOf(rating))
```

It's appearing like:

`You're about to rate this app with {String.valueOf(rating)} stars.`

Link Warning:

`Format string is not a valid format string so it should not be passed to string.format`

Note:

`v` is a `View` and `rating` is an `int` value.

I've checked other `strings.xml` files for other languages, and all translations seems alright.

Solved: for hindi string.xml, instead of %s, there was only %.

Comment: In string resources, you need to use %1$s (and %2$s etc.. for further variables)

Comment: It has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627457/format-statement-in-a-string-resource-file

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a position to each placeholder you define in your `XML`.

Your string then becomes:

```
<string name="rating_dialog">You\'re about to rate this app with %1$s stars.</string>
```

Comment: Thank you, I applied this (and checked untranslatable so translations can't have a impact) but still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below:

In string.xml:

If you want to assign integer value then use **"%1$d"** and if String then use **"%1$s"**

**1** is use for defining position. If you want to use multiple values then you can use "%1$d","%2$d",....etc

```
<string name="rating_dialog">You\'re about to rate this app with %1$d stars.</string>
```

Then in code do it like :

```
v.getContext().getString(R.string.rating_dialog, rating);
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you, I applied all your steps, with %1$d and %1$s and checked "untranslatable" in Translations Editor (so translations can't have a impact) but still the same problem.

Comment: can you please try like String message = getString(R.string.rating_dialog, rating); ?

Comment: The problem was the hindi strings.xml, instead of %s, there was only %. But thank you again