# Android Lint "is not a valid format string" error in string of xml file

Tags: android, string-formatting, android-lint

I want to display such a title in my screen, "**Up to 30% cheaper**".

So, I have this in my xml file: `<string name="title">Up to %d%% cheaper</string>`

and In code: `mTitle.setText(getString(R.string.title, 30));`

Although it works fine and I see above message however I am getting lint error that says:

[image]

How to get rid of this error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12627660/584140

Comment: People coming here because they were using `\%%` you might be able to fix this by simply removing the backslash, `%%` worked for me

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into the same problem, and found out how to resolve it:
You need to assign a position to your replacement strings. So instead of %d%%, you'd have to use `%1$d%%` (the `%1` denotes the position and the `$d` specifies the type). Also, contrary to what one would expect, `formatted="false"` does **NOT** remove the warning. In fact, only after I removed that part, the warning went away.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`<string name="title">Up to %1$d%% cheaper</string>`

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I tried that before and no difference. basically 1$ uses when there are multiple arguments otherwise there isn't any difference.