# How to pass parameters to strings resource which contains link in Android

Tags: android

I faced the following problem: there is the string resource which contains URL:

```
<string name="msg_more_information_about_credit"><![CDATA[<b>Ejemplo TAE:</b> 300€ a 62 días. <b>Coste préstamo:</b> 148€. <b>Total a devolver:</b> 448€. TAE 2035%. <a href="https://www.moneyman.es/secci.php?pers=0.011&tae=3112.64&back=290&back_date=22.11.2020&current_time=30&current_sum=290&is62=false">Más Información </a> ]]></string>
```

I need to make this link dynamic (pass values to it from code). For this purpose, I modified it a bit:

```
<string name="msg_more_information_about_credit"><![CDATA[<b>Ejemplo TAE:</b> 300€ a 62 días. <b>Coste préstamo:</b> 148€. <b>Total a devolver:</b> 448€. TAE 2035%. <a href="https://www.moneyman.es/secci.php?pers=0.011&tae=3112.64&back=290&back_date=%1$s&current_time=30&current_sum=290&is62=false">Más Información </a> ]]></string>
```

And then I tried to get resources as usual, when string contains other strings:

```
getString(R.string.msg_more_information_about_credit, "22.11.2020")
```

But in this case the link doesn't have my set value, but contains "%1$s"

So, my question is, how can I modify the link from code? Thanks in advance!

Comment: which data you want to pass dynamically? couldn't see "%1$s"

Comment: Have you tried to add `formatted="false"` to your string resource? https://stackoverflow.com/a/12627660

Comment: @ShaluTD, I am trying to pass a string to back_date parameter

Comment: @BrunoBieri added `formatted="false"`, but resut is the same

Comment: Have you also tried reading the string separately and in a second step to format it with `String.format(getString(..), "22.11.2020")` ?

Answer (score 1):

> **Step 1 :**
> Add string with link in your `string.xml` file.

```
<string name="mystringwithlink">Here is code how to put link into string xml \n<a href="https://stackoverflow.com">stackoverflow.com</a></string>
```

> **Step 2:**
> Then enter below line of code in your_activity.java

```
val linkTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.activity_main_link)
    
linkTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

If works perfectly then leave upvote for encouragement.

REF : [link](https://learntodroid.com/how-to-create-a-hyperlink-using-android-textview/)