# can you add some static string to a resource string in a view in xml

Tags: android

I have this in strings.xml:

```
<string name="function_varname">F</string>
```

and I want to have a TextView with the Text "F = ". is that possible? (only using xml and not just making a 2nd string)

Something like that:

```
android:text="@string/function_varname"+" = "
```

Comment: As far as I know you can not do that in xml only. You can use format strings and do it in code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627457/format-statement-in-a-string-resource-file